# C #define statement with # in macro name

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to declare a #define statement like this somehow?

```
    #define #Name# struct->name
```

I am getting the error "error: macro names must be identifiers" which I know is related to the # symbol. Is there a work around for allowing the # symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The name of a macro must be an identifier and `#` cannot appear in an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Macro names must be identifiers which means:

1. Must start with a letter or underscore.
2. Can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.

But the more important problem is that I don't think that the will do what you want anyway.  If `#define #Name# struct->name` were accepted, it wouldn't mean that `#foo#` would turn into `struct->foo` (which I assume is what you want.  If I'm wrong and you just want it to work for `#Name#` then just do something like `XNameX` instead.)  It would only work for the exact literal `#Name#`.  Instead, you want to do a macro which takes an argument like:

```
 #define X(name) struct->name
```

That will transform `X(foo)` to `struct->foo`.